# Pop-up not saving in Sketch mode

Tags: arcgis-online

I am using the new map viewer in ArcGIS online. When I add a point sketch layer and then click pop-up -> enable pop-up -> then add a title and text, there doesn't seem to be a button available to hit "done" or "save". So then, when I exit out of editing mode, no pop-up appears when I click on my point and when I try to edit the layer again I can see that "enable pop-up" was never saved. Is there something else I can do to save my pop-up preferences in sketch mode? Or, is anyone else aware of this being a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you make points with the default symbology, and then try to enable pop-ups in the initial sketch editing window, you can't retroactively add pop-ups to those points. If you go to -> current symbol -> pop-ups you can edit from there and then click "done" at the bottom.